# How to handle the exception on clicking an item from task bar

Tags: c#, winforms

The following is my code to find out the element from point,

```
Drawing.Point location = (Drawing.Point)param.Args[1];
point = new System.Windows.Point(Convert.ToDouble(location.X), Convert.ToDouble(location.Y));
element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
```

But this generates error when we are clicking a minimized window from task bar:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Comment: A hint: find which exactly operation caused the exception and what was the parameter's value before the operation .

Comment: @rs232   AutomationElement.FromPoint(point) generates error. The point is generation dynamically on each mouse click.It is valid

Comment: The exception is ArgumentException, I presume?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you, for better reproduceability, replace dynamic point generation with some fixed value which still reproduces an error?

Comment: @rs232 I created a global hook for capturing system mouse click events. Up on clicking a minimized notpad++ window from the taskbar Im getting this error. The x,y points that generates the error are 'Point 284,987'

Comment: That's a completely different story, actually. Do you capture WH_MOUSE or WH_MOUSE_LL events?

Comment: Its not an entire different scenario, I just explained my functionalities in my application,I thought it may help you to find out issue, If you try with the  values(284,987)that Im given to you, It also generating error.  Im Capturing both.

Comment: Okay, as you say it. If it is not an entirely different scenario, it should be pretty easy for you to reproduce the issue without hooks and provide a  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve